# Protractor browser chrome cache issue

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

Right now I'm running Protractor tests in chrome & while doing the automation I added a custom css class to a html file to catch that element for my automation.

But strangely when I run the test, the class I added was not reflected in my test browser. So I couldn't find the element correctly.

And I tried to go to a normal chrome window & check the new css class I added. It was there in a normal chrome window without any problem.

Do you have any idea what is happening here? Is this a cacheing issue?

I added a `browser.enterRepl();` & inspect in the test as well. But I couldn't see the new css class that I added.

I tried with adding a `id` & same thing is happening

Comment: I have the same problem, but the accepted answer does not solve it for me.  I ran the test in incognito, and the test window is still using outdated css.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are thinking it is the cache issue, try opening Chrome in Incognito mode by adding this settings to your conf.js:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['incognito']
    }
  }
```